# Memory allocation of array in a struct

Tags: c, arrays, memory, struct, zmalloc

I read the code of redis, it define a struct:

```
typedef struct zskiplistNode {
    robj *obj;
    double score;
    struct zskiplistNode *backward;
    struct zskiplistLevel {
        struct zskiplistNode *forward;
        unsigned int span;
    } level[];
} zskiplistNode;
```

and it create node like this:

```
zskiplistNode *zn = zmalloc(sizeof(*zn)+level*sizeof(struct zskiplistLevel));
```

Is that mean, if the address of `zn` is `0x10000`, then `&(zn->level[0])` is `0x10000+sizeof(zskiplistNode)`, the memory address of array is behind the struct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zn->level` (a flexible array member) has some fixed offset w.r.t. `zn`: if `zn` is at address `0x10000`, then `zn->level[0]` could be at address `0x10018` because the pointer `robj` would occupy one 8byte word (assuming a 64 bits x86 machine) and the double `score` would occupy another 8 byte word -and should be word aligned- and the pointer `backward` would occupy another word. So `zn->level` is offset by 3 words, i.e. 24 bytes (i.e. `0x18` in hex).

BTW, the compiler or ABI could insert gaps in your structure (for alignment or ABI compliance). In your particular example it probably would not (with GCC on Linux/x86-64).

You could be interested by the standard [offsetof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offsetof) macro and of course the `sizeof` "operator".